# SlideInEffect and TurnstileFeatherEffect not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

Anyone ever had problems with `SlideInEffect` and `TurnstileFeatherEffect` from windows phone toolkit?

I am trying to make `SlideInEffect`  work on `LongListSelector` and `LongListMultiSelector` with no luck so far.

Also the `TurnstileFeatherEffect` does not work when the page is loading but it does work when navigating away from them. Same applies to all pages (panorama / pivot / normal pages).

Take for example this code on a normal page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SamplePage.Pages.About"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--Transitions-->
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="ABOUT" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="#404041" FontWeight="Bold" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="24,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Image Height="100" Source="/Assets/Images/logo.png" Margin="-5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="1"/>

                <StackPanel Margin="0,90,0,0">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="2">
                        <Image Height="76" Width="76" Margin="-16,0,-20,0" Source="/Assets/AppBar/appbar.shield.png"/>
                        <HyperlinkButton Foreground="#FF474747" NavigateUri="http://sample.com/" TargetName="_anything" Content="Privacy Policy"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="3" Margin="0,-20,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Height="76" Width="76" Margin="-16,0,-20,0" Source="/Assets/AppBar/appbar.email.png"/>
                        <HyperlinkButton Foreground="#FF474747" NavigateUri="http://sample.com/" TargetName="_anything" Content="Send Feedback"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

                <ScrollViewer Margin="0,210,0,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Margin="2,0,12,0">
                            <!-- HEADER -->
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Version" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF363636" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="4"/>
                            <!-- BODY -->
                            <RichTextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="-10,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FF363636" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="5">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="0.0.1"/>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </RichTextBox>

                            <!-- HEADER -->
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Description" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF363636" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="6"/>
                            <!-- BODY -->
                            <RichTextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="-10,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FF363636" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="7">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."/>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </RichTextBox>

                            <!-- HEADER -->
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Developed by" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF363636" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="8"/>
                            <!-- BODY -->
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="440" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="9">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Assets/Images/logo.png"></Image>
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Assets/Images/logo.png"></Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Also note that I changed `RootFrame`to `new TransitionFrame()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found the problem.

So it seems like on some pages where feather transitions are not supported you have to you use the normal transitions:

```
    <!--Transitions-->
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

After putting that on the MainPage.xaml which happens to be a panorama everything else works just fine.

Comment: Did you find out what causes it, or is it just trial and error for every page?

Comment: If I am not mistaken panorama does not support any other transitions than the one above. Since toolkit is not yet updated I think you cant use it anymore. Anyhow I don't find Panorama pages to be good anymore. I'd rather use pivot and make it full screen.